# CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE is not allowed with ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED or KEY_BLOCK_SIZE.,

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, reindex

My Magento 2 site can't be indexed anymore.

not sure what created the problem, when I run **php bin/magento indexer:reindex**, It shows following error

> userxx@host [~/public_html/magento2]# php bin/magento indexer:reindex
>   Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
>   Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00 Category
>   Products indexer process unknown error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General
>   error: 4047 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE is not allowed with
>   ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED or KEY_BLOCK_SIZE., query was: CREATE TEMPORARY
>   TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `shrp_catalog_category_product_index_store1_tmp`
>   LIKE `shrp_catalog_category_product_index_store1` Product Categories
>   indexer process unknown error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 4047
>   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE is not allowed with ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED or
>   KEY_BLOCK_SIZE., query was: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
>   `shrp_catalog_category_product_index_store1_tmp` LIKE
>   `shrp_catalog_category_product_index_store1` Catalog Rule Product
>   index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00 Product EAV index has
>   been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00 Stock index has been rebuilt
>   successfully in 00:00:00 Inventory index has been rebuilt successfully
>   in 00:00:00 Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully
>   in 00:00:00 Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in
>   00:00:00 Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in
>   00:00:00 userxx@host [~/public_html/magento2]#

[image]

I'm using Magento ver 2.3.2

I googled it but couldn't find any useful info on this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the row format of the shrp_catalog_category_product_index_store1 table being COMPRESSED (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-row-format.html).  You can change it with the query "ALTER TABLE shrp_catalog_category_product_index_store1 row_format=DYNAMIC;" and the indexing should work.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks Ryan.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Worked perfectly. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

As Ryan mentioned above; the sql statement below can solve your issue:

```
ALTER TABLE shrp_catalog_category_product_index_store1 row_format=DYNAMIC
```

Please note that **shrp_** refers to table prefix in database. You might be using a different table prefix in your database. So, modify and execute the above sql query accordingly.

Also, there might be more than 1 table so this query needs to be executed for them.

The tables might be numbered like: **shrp_catalog_category_product_index_store2, shrp_catalog_category_product_index_store3, shrp_catalog_category_product_index_store4** etc.

In this case you need to execute query like this:

```
ALTER TABLE shrp_catalog_category_product_index_store2 row_format=DYNAMIC
ALTER TABLE shrp_catalog_category_product_index_store3 row_format=DYNAMIC
ALTER TABLE shrp_catalog_category_product_index_store4 row_format=DYNAMIC
```

Please check your database and execute the above query for all iterations of: **catalog_category_product_index_store**

Comment: you have idea about this question ? this question is same like
https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/287929/68695